# Can I put an object into varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I want to push to Varnish specific url to cache it after processing. Flow:

1. processing image
2. when finished "push" url reference to the image to varnish to cache it

I do not want to wait for requests by clients to cache it then. It should be ready after processing to return it with high performance. Is it possible?

I can send an internal request GET like a standard client and make it cached, but I would prefer defining i.e PUT request in varnish config, and make it cached without returning it in that process.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is an internal `HEAD` (better than `GET`; it will be internally converted to a `GET` by Varnish when submitting the request to the backend side). The `PUT` approach is not possible, at least not without implementing a VMOD for it, and it probably won't be a simple one.